# How to save data using CoreData without write values two times on Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a `DataHandler`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {

    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    class func saveProduct(p : [String: Any]) {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product", in: context)
        let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        manageObject.setValue(p["default_code"], forKey: "default_code")
        manageObject.setValue(p["name"], forKey: "name")
        manageObject.setValue(p["id"], forKey: "id")
        manageObject.setValue(p["display_name"], forKey: "display_name")

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Salvo com sucesso! \(String(describing: p["display_name"]))")
        } catch {
            print("Erro ao salvar: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have an `Entity "Product"`:

[image]

I have a `ViewController` that I insert values for test:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var products: [Product]? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)

        var aux: [String:Any] = [:]
        aux["name"] = "Nome do produto 4"
        aux["default_code"] = "myDefaul_Code 4"
        aux["id"] = 144
        aux["display_name"] = "Nome para mostrar 4"

        CoreDataHandler.saveProduct(p: aux)
        products = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()

        for i in products! {
            print(i.display_name!)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

My problem is:

I set the attributes two times! One in `ViewController.swift` and other in the `CoreDataHandler.swift` via `manageObject.setValue`. I want to set it only once and save in the database! Is there a way to do so? I have entities in my project with more than 100 attributes! Will **CoreData** help me to implement this requirement?

Comment: Since you've defined `Product` in a core data model file, Xcode will automatically generate the class definition for you. You can write `let p = Product()`, insert it into the managed object context, and then set its properties with e.g. `p.name = "Nome do prodoto 4"`. Then you don't even need a `saveProduct` function. If you write a convenience initializer for `Product` in an extension, then you will have very clean code.

Comment: Dictionaries have a `keys` property which is an array of all the keys used in a `Dictionary`. So, by simply iterating, you could avoid setting values inside your class manually again. Something like `for key in p.keys { manageObject.setValue(p[key], forKey: key) }`

Comment: @BallpointBen how I insert into the managed object context?

Comment: @Augusto https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640602-init I would pass the context to your convenience initializer, and then inside the convenience initializer call that initializer using the passed context.

Comment: I wrote : let p = Product(), how I call init?

Comment: Please, you can reply my question with a example? I don't understand the apple docs

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a dictionary you could make sure that the keys in the dictionary corresponds to the attribute names for your entity and then in the save func iterate over the dictionary

```
for (key, value) in p {
    manageObject.setValue(value, forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: Instead of the for loop you can just call ```managedObject.setValuesForKeys(p)```

Comment: @pfandrade, thank you. I was looking for a method like that but managed to miss it.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the CoreDataHandler class you only defined a "saveProduct" method (function) to save the values. The class itself does nothing.

In your view controller viewDidLoad method you have to create an instance of the CoreDataHandler:

```
let handler = CoreDataHandler()
```

and then call that "saveProduct" method on the handler instance which you instantiated:

```
handler.saveProduct(...)
```

So you actually only set the values once, namely in your view controller during "viewDidLoad".

Comment: I don't understand.